# icon for title in view in drupal

Tags: drupal, icons, viewmodel

I'm using drupal as script for my web site 
i creat a page to list all node of a content type name Math , the page was created with simpleview and i edited the page to show node title username and picture of the user the only problem is that i want to add icon to each node title the icon will be the same like for exemple the icon in the forum the folder with the star like the exemple in the drupal advanced forum

http://drupal.org/files/af-forums.png

is it possile and if it possible how can i do it

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield to create a field in view for each row depend on your need. In this field just specify `<img href="your file path"/>` tag.